# Validating Entity Framework 6 entities that have similar properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm using entity framework 6 (created from my database model), and have a table called users, of which I have some related tables called UserXml, UserExtranet, UserCustomer, all of these tables have the same fields.

The tables are linked by foreign keys.

Based on the user type e.g Xml/Extranet/Customer, I need to perform validation like is the UserXml enabled, or is the UserExtranet enabled.

Here is a snippet of what I have at the moment

```
//find the user
User oUser = Context.User.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Email == this.Email);

if (oUser != null)
{
   var oUserType = (dynamic)null;
   int iMaxAttempts;
   bool bValidIp = false; 

   //authenticate the type of user
   switch (this.Type)
   {
      case UserType.Xml:
          oUserType = oUser.UserXml; 
          //do the validation           
          break;

      case UserType.Api:
          oUserType = oUser.UserApi; 
          //do the validation           
          break;
      default:
          oUserType = null;
          break;
   }
```

}

Here are my entities.

The user class

```
public partial class User
{
    public User()
    {
    }

    public long UserId { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public virtual UserCustomer UserCustomer { get; set; }
    public virtual UserExtranet UserExtranet { get; set; }
    public virtual UserXml UserXml { get; set; }
}
```

The customer class

```
public partial class UserCustomer
{
    public UserCustomer()
    {

    }

    public long UserId { get; set; }
    public long SiteId { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Salt { get; set; }
    public byte FailedAttempts { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime LastLogin { get; set; }
    public bool Enabled { get; set; }
    public bool Deleted { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime LastChanged { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

The UserExtranet class

```
public partial class UserExtranet
{
    public UserExtranet()
    {
    }

    public long UserId { get; set; }
    public long SiteId { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Salt { get; set; }
    public byte FailedAttempts { get; set; }
    public bool Enabled { get; set; }
    public bool Deleted { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime LastChanged { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

The UserXml class

```
public partial class UserXml
{
    public UserXml()
    {
    }

    public long UserId { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Salt { get; set; }
    public byte FailedAttempts { get; set; }
    public bool Enabled { get; set; }
    public bool Deleted { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime LastChanged { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

How best can I achieve this without doubling up the code for each table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a fourth class called UserModel and cast your various User objects to it, then validate the UserModel.

```
public partial class UserModel
{
public UserModel()
{

}

public long UserId { get; set; }
public long SiteId { get; set; }
public string Email { get; set; }
public string Password { get; set; }
public string Salt { get; set; }
public byte FailedAttempts { get; set; }
public System.DateTime LastLogin { get; set; }
public bool Enabled { get; set; }
public bool Deleted { get; set; }
public System.DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
public System.DateTime LastChanged { get; set; }

public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

And then

```
//find the user
User oUser = Context.User.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Email == this.Email);

if (oUser != null)
{
var oUserType = (dynamic)null;
int iMaxAttempts;
bool bValidIp = false; 

var ModelUser = new UserModel(){ UserId = oUser,UserId, etc.};

//authenticate the type of user
switch (this.Type)
{
   case UserType.Xml:
       oUserType = oUser.UserXml; 

      break;

  case UserType.Api:
      oUserType = oUser.UserApi; 

      break;
  default:
      oUserType = null;
      break;
}
ModelUser.Validate();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, another thought I just had I could use AutoMapper maybe in a similar manner ?

Comment: Yes. I wanted to mention AutoMapper, but I decided against it simply because I didn't think it was important HOW the mapping happens. But definitely user AutoMapper. Pro Tip: when using AutoMapper with EF, return IQueryable instead of IEnumerable so that the enumeration only happens when you need it to. Much better for Memory management and CPU time.

Comment: Is this the common practice when using Entity Framework, and similar entities ?

Comment: Don't know. But it makes sense. If you map a large collection of entities to concrete types, they're all in memory hogging resources. If you map them to IQueryable, execution is deferred to when you explicitly need it.